# How do I know which vagrantfile is in use?

Tags: vagrant

This seems to be common problem:
Lets say i have a project which has Vagrantfile. So i executed "vagrant up" and vagrant machine is up and running. So for so good.

After few days i synced the same project codebase to another location on same machine and tried to execute vagrant up. But this time it failed saying "vagrant cant forward request to this port 8080". This is because another vagrant instance occupied this port 8080.

Now if i want to know from where this vagrant box spin off, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will tell you the state of all Vagrant environments:

```
$ vagrant global-status
```

If you would stop any machin, you can use:

```
$ vagrant halt id
```

Comment: Thank you @k0chan . It saved my time.